# помогите создать батник на выключение компа

Tags: cmd

Нужно сделать батник,который будет вырубать компьютер в промежутке с 22 вечера до 7 утра.никогда их не писал,прошу помочь. Батник должен при запуске компа проверять время системы и вырубать ее тут же

Comment: Если вы не специалист и не собираетесь им становится -- то лучше всего вам обратиться на биржу фриланса, чтобы вам написали под ключ. Здесь же не любят вопросы в стиле "напишите за меня код", но помогают разобраться, если спрашивающий сам прикладывает усилия. Начинайте писать, спрашивайте конкретные вопросы -- шансы получить помощь будут гораздо выше.

Comment: @A K Да какая тут биржа фриланса? Это задачка чуть ли не для начинающих. Погуглить чуть-чуть и всё.

Comment: вам не батник нужен, а шедулер

Comment: Вообще в Windows есть родительский контроль и с помощью него можно выполнить данную задачу

Comment: можете использовать сторонний софт: http://www.softportal.com/software-1036-poweroff.html

Comment: @stack-it Использовать софт для того, что можно сделать с помощью операционной системы - это моветон.

Comment: @ilyaplot поясните что значит моветон, в данном случает и почему вы против использования софта для настроек отключение пк.

Answer (score 3):

Батник не нужен. Создайте в планировщике задание. Название свободное, но лучше типа "Выключить в 22:00". Триггер - ежедневно в 22:00. Действие - запуск программы `%SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /s /t 60 /f` (60 - это столько секунд система будет ожидать команду отмены `shutdown /a`, если отмена гарантированно не нужна, поставьте ноль). Общие - выбрать "Выполнять вне зависимости от регистрации пользователя" и поставить галку "Запускать с высшими правами". Почти всё собственно.

Остаётся только заблокировать запуск (точнее, аутентификацию) в запрещённое время. Это уже делается настройками родительского контроля - запретом времени в промежутке с 22 вечера до 7 утра для каждой учётной записи. Причём блокировать можно только те учётные записи, которые имеют тип "Обычный пользователь" - на учётные записи с административными привилегиями (и/или входящие в другие локальные группы, кроме группы Пользователи) ограничения родительского контроля не распространяются.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
IF %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% GEQ 2200 GOTO poweroff
IF %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% LEQ 0700 GOTO poweroff
GOTO end
:poweroff
shutdown /s /t 0
:end
```

Вставьте этот скрипт в bat файл, а bat файл добавьте в автозагрузку и через каждые минут 10. Лучше это сделать через назначенные задания. Скрипт написал только для саморзавития. В комментариях правы, вам с денежками на фриланс надо идти.